# Connecting to PiHole changes my computer's hostname?

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn, hostname, pihole

I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/rajannpatel/Pi-Hole-PiVPN-on-Google-Compute-Engine-Free-Tier-with-Full-Tunnel-and-Split-Tunnel-OpenVPN-Configs) to create a VM in Google Cloud Platform that hosts PiHole (a DNS-based ad-blockign service) for me. To prevent the terrors of an open DNS provider, the PiHole is protected behind an OpenVPN server.

My router (Asus RT-AC68U) run an OpenVPN client which connects to the PiHole, and has its DNS servers set to `10.8.0.1` (the PiHole over the VPN) and blank.

When I'm at work, my computer's hostname is `Alexs-Work-MacBook-Pro.local`. But when I connect at home (behind this PiHoled router), my hostname changes to `Alexs-Work-MBP.local`.

If I replace the second blank DNS server with `1.1.1.1` (or some other provider), and restart my WiFi, my hostname goes back to `Alexs-Work-MacBook-Pro.local`.

What gives?

Comment: Are you talking about your computer's local hostname or the public address hostname?

Comment: @Ecstasy Could you please explain the difference? I think I'm talking about my "local hostname", the one that comes up when I run the `hostname` command in bash